Mismatching data type when importing csv in snowflake with dbt
I upload csv to snowflake with dbt seed.
my test.csv:
ID,SOURCES
8dabe,["test"]
9ef9c,["test"]

But I need a column (SOURCES) to be a VARIANT type instead of a VARCHAR type. To this end I create a properties.yml files for the seeds:
version: 2
seeds:
  - name: test
    config:
      column_types:
        SOURCES: VARIANT

However it returns this error:
Expression type does not match column data type, expecting VARIANT but got VARCHAR(8) for column SOURCES
What sould I change in my csv or my yml ?

you could also cast the datatype in a dbt model instead

I don't think you can natively load a variant/array that looks like a field from CSV to a Snowflake table. However, it is possible to ingest variant fields from more complex data formats like JSON and Parquet.
You can load comma-separated strings or convert strings to variants after it is ingested into Snowflake.
select parse_json('["test"]');

I tried to reproduce the issue by inserting a record in snowflake.
Can you try replacing double quotes with single quotes eg: 'test'
Create table with variant column
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
    Id variant
);

This fails
insert into table1 select ["test"];

This succeeds
insert into table1 select ['test'];

